# Why shouldn't you use these woods when building a hugelkultur?

Tags: raised-beds, hugelkultur

Someone asked a question on what woods not to use, so I'm wondering why you shouldn't use these wood types when building a [hugelkultur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%BCgelkultur) (raised bed used to either conserve water, or increase surface area on top of rotting wood):

- cedar
- camphor wood
- black locust
- black cherry
- black walnut
- pine
- fir

Comment: Black walnut can prevent other plants from growing, I've heard. Cedar and camphor may not be attractive to insects (which may be beneficial for this). I don't know about Black Cherry, but I've perhaps heard that cherry can take a while to decompose. Those might be some things to research and see if they're an issue.

Comment: Cedar, Camphor, Black Locust, Black Walnut, and certain varieties of Fir are all very slow or resistant to decomposition. This would reduce their usefulness in a hugelkultur. Not sure about the others.

Comment: I'm looking for the wiki style answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The types of wood that you have mentioned contain tannins that negatively affect the [germination and the growth of the plants, nitrogen availability and photosynthesis](http://www.insa.nic.in/writereaddata/UpLoadedFiles/PINSA/Vol51B_1985_2_Art15.pdf). They are also [toxic for some microorganisms](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/223084771_Antimicrobial_properties_of_tannin).